# Matplotlib not functioning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to learn matplotlib and I've just downloaded it and am going through some basic functions. No matter how I use it, I get the same error. I'm copying and pasting code from tutorial websites and it still doesn't work. I'm on windows and am using visual studio code. For example, I've used this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

and I get this error:

> PS C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Code\Python\Surveying_Program> &
> C:/Users/Tim/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe
> c:/Users/Tim/Desktop/Code/Python/Matplotlib_practice.py Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Code\Python\Matplotlib_practice.py", line 7, in
>
> fig, ax = plt.subplots()   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 1432, in subplots
> fig = figure(**fig_kw)   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib_api\deprecation.py",
> line 454, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 773, in figure
> manager = new_figure_manager(   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 348, in new_figure_manager
> _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 338, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
> if (_get_required_interactive_framework(_get_backend_mod()) and   File
> "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 207, in *get_backend_mod
> switch_backend(dict.**getitem**(rcParams, "backend"))   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 252, in switch_backend
> switch_backend(candidate)   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 265, in switch_backend
> backend_mod = importlib.import_module(   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 883, in
> exec_module   File "", line 241, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qtagg.py",
> line 12, in 
> from .backend_qt import QtCore, QtGui, _BackendQT, FigureCanvasQT   File
> "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py",
> line 72, in 
> _MODIFIER_KEYS = [   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py",
> line 73, in 
> (_to_int(getattr(_enum("QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier"), mod)), TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> real number, not 'KeyboardModifier' PS
> C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Code\Python\Surveying_Program>

I really appreciate any help.

I've tried redownloading via pip and it's still not working for me.

Comment: That error did not come from this code.  There is no keyboard stuff, and there are no calls to int().  Please show us the entire traceback.

Comment: Apologies, I've added the entire error message.

Comment: This is some strange interaction between matplotlib and Qt.  Can you try adding `import matplotlib` / `matplotlib.use('tkagg')` at the top of your file, as an experiment?

Comment: Well, that fixed it. This is somehow related to Tkinter, correct? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: What that says is to use Tkinter to generate the plot windows, not Qt.  Users will probably not notice.  I assume this is a transient thing that will get fixed in some upgrade.